# Need to spilt string twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

As I'm still learning python I need some help.

Below is a sting that I need 2 separate lots of information out of. I've looked up how to get information out of strings but all examples ether put in a list or use numbers

```
msg= 'MFS: *CFSRES INC0020 01/12/14 07:51 RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1, 123 TESTSTREET TESTTOWN ,MAP: ,TG 100, == TESTING : UNIT HERE'
```

SO the information I want is 1 )RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1 2) =TESTING:

The sting will always change but the words RESPOND and the = will always be there.

The code I have tried:

```
msg='MFS: *CFSRES INC0020 01/12/14 07:51 RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1, 123 TESTSTREET TESTTOWN ,MAP: ,TG 100, == TESTING : UNIT HERE'
print msg.split(RESPOND)
```

output is

```
'MFS: *CFSRES INC0020 01/12/14 07:51 "," TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1, 123 TESTSTREET TESTTOWN ,MAP: ,TG 100, == TESTING : UNIT HERE'
```

So I'm guessing that `string.split()` is not I what I would use or do need to use it in a different way?

Edit: using with pyttsx so getting main info out as string is so long

Comment: I'm confused as to what information you want. Do you want all information after RESPOND TEST ONLY including it? Can you show me what your desired output would be?

Comment: trying to achieve is msg1= RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL:1 msg2= TESTING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was commented before you should give us more information on what data you want to extract from the string.

Depending on how complex that is you should probably go with a regular expression instead. The Python [HowTo](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) is quite good as an introduction.

Your example could be solved as follows:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(?P<prefix>.*)RESPOND(?P<middle>.*?)=(?P<postfix>.*)')

msg = 'MFS: *CFSRES INC0020 01/12/14 07:51 RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1, 123 TESTSTREET TESTTOWN ,MAP: ,TG 100, == TESTING : UNIT HERE'

match = pattern.match(msg)

if match:
    print '[PREFIX]', match.group('prefix')
    print '[MIDDLE]', match.group('middle')
    print '[POSTFIX]', match.group('postfix')
else:
    print 'NO MATCH!!'
```

Output:

```
[PREFIX] MFS: *CFSRES INC0020 01/12/14 07:51 
[MIDDLE]  TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1, 123 TESTSTREET TESTTOWN ,MAP: ,TG 100, 
[POSTFIX] = TESTING : UNIT HERE
```

Depending on what data you want you can modify the regular expression to almost anything.

**EDIT:**

I have adjusted the regexpr so that the result is what you want.
You could do much more, e.g. extract the alarm level as a number, etc.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('.*(RESPOND.*?ALARM\sLEVEL.*?),.*==\s(.*)\s:')

msg = 'MFS: *CFSRES INC0020 01/12/14 07:51 RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1, 123 TESTSTREET TESTTOWN ,MAP: ,TG 100, == TESTING : UNIT HERE'

match = pattern.match(msg)

if match:
  for group in match.groups():
      print group
else:
    print 'NO MATCH!!'
```

Output:

```
RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1
TESTING
```

Comment: the only info i need is RESPOND TEST ONLY, ALARM LEVEL: 1 & = TESTING the rest is not needed

Comment: Ok, i will simplify it a little. give me a minute.

Comment: ok cheers also RESPOND is missing. im using this with pyttsx as you can see im extraction main info

Comment: Thanks now i shall look at it and play so i know how to do it next time.